# Is there any way to disable/enable notfication of my iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, ios6

My app contain a uiswitch that  give the user an option to disable/enable notIfication of my iphone app
So i need code of disable/enable notification,
Thanks

Comment: Did you read the Appl guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Comment: check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510578/enable-or-disable-iphone-push-notifications-inside-the-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes (enable) or unregisterForRemoteNotificationTypes (disable)