# How to handle logout event using push notifications?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

I have an app where I want to unregister for push notifications when the user logout. This can simply be done using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

However, is there no way to register (or prompt for registration) once a user login at a later time?
Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2438400/1075405) question suggest there is not, so what is then the recommended way of handling this?

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) of notification services gives, as far as I can tell, no clue how to handle this.
All suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot re register for push notification programmatically. You must have to manage this by server side. See the answer

[Enable or Disable Iphone Push Notifications inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510578/enable-or-disable-iphone-push-notifications-inside-the-app)

Comment: This appear to be true...Well well, better tell the server guys to start working! ^^