# How to disable push notification from app for that app only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am developing an app which accepts push notifications. I want to disable the push notifications for that app only by just toggling `UISwitch` in the app settings. So is it possible that I can enable or disable the push notifications from the app itself?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510578/enable-or-disable-iphone-push-notifications-inside-the-app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Please take a look on *registerForRemoteNotifications* and *unregisterForRemoteNotifications* methods ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication))