# Is it possible to control push receive setting inside iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios10

Someone gave me the task to develop push setting

- that user can set (receive/do not receive) push notification.

I'm confused because I thought it's not possible to control it inside an  application.

Is it possible to control push receive setting inside iOS App?
may be in newer version?

Comment: You can't change the notification permissions. What you can do is do is tell your server not to send notifications to your device.

Comment: you can use `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes `  and `unregisterForRemoteNotificationTypes` for enable and disable push notification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable or Disable Iphone Push Notifications inside the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510578/enable-or-disable-iphone-push-notifications-inside-the-app)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623078-registerforremotenotifications

Comment: According to my coworker, there will be no sever side coding, we will directly send apple server to send push notification to user, and the Language I am using is swift 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can not control push notification setting from your app.

But you can manage BOOL flag in `NSUserDefault`.

As per setting your BOOL value will change, so in push notification delegate methods you can use directly apply `return` keyword to do not process for notification.